# How do I upgrade from pip 1.0?

Tags: python, pip, upgrade

I was trying to install a package which required an older version of pip and (stupidly) thought it would be a good idea to try installing the oldest version of pip possible (1.0).
To clarify, it is not pip 1.0.1 (which most guides I found on the internet refer to), but pip 1.0

When I attempt to run 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip', I get the following error:

```sh
C:\mydirectory\venv\Scripts\python.exe: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

When I run 'pip --version', I get the following info:

```sh
pip 1.0 from c:\mydirectory\venv\lib\site-packages (python 3.7)
```

Is there any way I can upgrade pip from this point?

Comment: lol, next time check the requirements, im pretty sure `python -m pip install -U pip` works!

Answer (score 3):

`python -m pip install -U pip` should work. That is how I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
python3 -m pip  install pip
```